# Specific array in parameters Alamofire Swift

Tags: json, xcode, swift, xcode7, alamofire

```
 let parameters = [
        "par1":"create",
        "comments":"Тестовый заказ",
        "fio":"Данил Иванов Иванович",
        "client":[
            "user_id": "482",
            "city_id": "1",
            "phone": "+79181442810",
            "address": "Пушкина 34"
        ],
        "order_items": [
            [
                "id": "1932",
                "quantity": "2",
                "comment": "test"
            ],
            [
            "id": "1932",
            "quantity": "3",
            "comment": "test"
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

this is my parameters, which requests with Alamofire.

```
Manager.request(.POST, "http://buffet.softkb.ru/buffet/order/create", parameters: parameters, headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"])
        .responseSwiftyJSON({ (request, response, json, error) in
            print("get")
            print(json)
            print(error)
            if error == nil {

                if json["msg_code"] != 0 {
                    self.showAlert("Ошибка", message: "\(json["msg_text"])", button: "ОК")
                } else {
                }
            }
    })
```

Server must be accepts something like that:

```
    

array (
      'par1' => 'create',
      'comments' => '',
      'fio' => 'Афонина юлия Юрьевна ',
      'client' =>
      array (
        'user_id' => '482',
        'city_id' => '1',
        'phone' => '+79529951385',
        'address' => '1 микр общ 13 кв 13',
      ),
      'order_items' =>
      array (
        0 =>
        array (
          'id' => '1932',
          'quantity' => '2',
          'comment' => '',
        ),
        1 =>
        array (
          'id' => '2044',
          'quantity' => '1',
          'comment' => '',
        ),
        2 =>
        array (
          'id' => '2154',
          'quantity' => '1',
          'comment' => '',
        ),
        3 =>
        array (
          'id' => '2025',
          'quantity' => '2',
          'comment' => '',
        ),
      ),
```

but it accepts this:

```
 array (
     'par1' => 'create',
     'comments' => 'Тестовый заказ',
     'fio' => 'Афонина Юлия Юрьевна',
     'client' => '["user_id":482, "ctiy_id": 1, "phone": "+79181672810", "address": "пушкина 34"]',
     'order_items' => '[["id": 1932, "quantity":3, "comment":""],["id": 1932, "quantity":3, "comment":""]]',
   ),
```

I guess, that must be something different, when i filling array by array, or something else
How can i fix this? Thank you very much for help

Comment: Can you explain the error you get from server?

Comment: There is an error, which don't accepts a user_id parameter, because its just not see him. I don't know why.

Comment: Try to set it as String

Comment: What i should set to String?

Comment: because your server seems accepts it as String `array (
        'user_id' => '482',
        'city_id' => '1',
        'phone' => '+79529951385',
        'address' => '1 микр общ 13 кв 13',
      )`

Comment: @ciccioska you saying about parameters? user_id?

Comment: yes, the user_id param..

Comment: @ciccioska I'm already do this( same issue